# Why does my Java code output 10 instead of -1 in this situation, and how do I fix it?

Tags: java

I'm making a static method, "indexOfKeyword", and it is meant to return an indexOf a string when the string isn't embedded into another word—it's meant to return -1 when that does not occur.

Given

```java
String s = "She sells seashells by the seashore.";
String keyword = "sea";
```

the output is meant to be -1 because the keyword "sea" is embedded into each word; however, my code outputs 10 instead, the first occurrence where it finds "sea" in "seashells".

If a string has an occurrence where it stands alone in the beginning, like

```java
String s = "Carolyn has a car that is scary fast.";
String keyword = "car";
```

I made it where `startIdx` has to be greater than 0 so that the "Car" in "Carolyn" does not get picked up. When the above is inputted into the code below, it works as intended, outputting correctly 14.

Here is the code in its entirety, verbatim, that should be outputting -1:

```java
public class Chatter {
    public static int indexOfKeyword(String s, String keyword) {
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
        int startIdx = s.indexOf(keyword);
        while (startIdx >= 0) {
            String before = " ", after = " ";
            if (startIdx > 0) {
                before = s.substring(startIdx - 1, startIdx);
            }
            int endIdx = startIdx;
            if (endIdx < s.length()) {
                after = s.substring((startIdx + keyword.length()), (startIdx + keyword.length() + 1));
            }
            if (!(before.compareTo("a") >= 0 && before.compareTo("z") <= 0 && after.compareTo("a") >= 0
                    && after.compareTo("z") <= 0)) {
                if (startIdx > 0) {
                    return startIdx;
                }
            }
            startIdx = s.indexOf(keyword, s.indexOf(keyword) + 1);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ... and test it here
        String s = "She sells seashells by the seashore.";
        String keyword = "sea";
        System.out.println(indexOfKeyword(s, keyword));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to re-invent the wheel. Regex already got you covered: [How to find index of whole word in string in java](//stackoverflow.com/q/42622944)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to find a particular word and not a particular substring.

There are two errors in your method `indexOfKeyword`.

1. The condition in the `while` loop is wrong. You need to split it into two, separate conditions.
2. Setting `startIdx`, in order to search for the next occurrence of `keyword` is also wrong.

Compare your code with the code below.

```
public static int indexOfKeyword(String s, String keyword) {
    int startIdx = s.indexOf(keyword);
    while (startIdx >= 0) {
        String before = " ", after = " ";
        if (startIdx > 0) {
            before = s.substring(startIdx - 1, startIdx);
        }
        int endIdx = startIdx;
        if (endIdx < s.length()) {
            after = s.substring((startIdx + keyword.length()), (startIdx + keyword.length() + 1));
        }
        if (!(before.compareTo("a") >= 0 && before.compareTo("z") <= 0)) {
            if (!(after.compareTo("a") >= 0 && after.compareTo("z") <= 0)) {
                if (startIdx > 0) {
                    return startIdx;
                }
            }
        }
        startIdx = s.indexOf(keyword, startIdx + 1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As @Tom mentioned, in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74766620/why-does-my-java-code-output-10-instead-of-1-in-this-situation-and-how-do-i-fi#comment131953985_74766620), there are other ways to solve the problem. I assume that your purpose is to come up with and implement your own algorithm, hence I have shown you where you have gone wrong in your implementation.

Note that a single space is not the only way to delimit words in a sentence, for example two words, in a sentence, may be separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, mayby I've got your intentions incorrectly, but have you considered wrapping your keyward with spaces before searching?

Something like this should (theoretically) work:

```java
public static int indexOfKeyword(String s, String keyword) {
    String source = s.toLowerCase();
    String key = " " + keyword.toLowerCase() + " ";
    return source.indexOf(key);
}
```

Or (as [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) has noted) RegEx might be used, however this solution is more complicated and might be not as obvious as you wanted it to be.

In your case it might look like this:

```java
public static int indexOfKeyword(String s, String keyword) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\s" + keyword + "\\s", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s);
    return m.find() ? m.start() : -1;
}
```